# Duvida de if else

Tags: c, if, else

Boa noite, fui testar este código C de uma atividade* do meu curso,
funciona ok o if (c<101||c>103), funciona ok o else if (c=101), porém o else if (c=102) ao invés de me retornar ns=s+(s*0.2), está me retornando o anterior, ns=s+(s*0.1), o mesmo ocorre com o else if (c=103) que devia retornar ns=s+(s*0.3) mas também retorna ns=s+(s*0.1).
Poderiam me tirar a dúvida de qual o problema e como devejo corrigi-lá?
Obrigado.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

main()

{
float s,c,ns;
printf ("Cod. do Cargo:");
scanf ("%f",&c);
printf ("Salario:");
scanf ("%f",&s);
if (c<101||c>103)
{
 ns=s+(s*0.4);
}
else if (c=101)
{
 ns=s+(s*0.1);
}
else if (c=102)
{
 ns=s+(s*0.2);
}
else if (c=103)
{
 ns=s+(s*0.3);
}
printf ("Salario Antigo: R$ %.2f",s);
printf ("\nNovo Salario: R$ %.2f",ns);
printf ("\nDiferenca: R$ %.2f",ns-s);
}
```

*

> *A atividade era esta: Uma empresa concederá um aumento de salário aos seus funcionários, variável de acordo com o cargo, conforme a tabela
>   abaixo. Faça um algoritmo que leia o salário e o cargo de um
>   funcionário e calcule o novo salário. Se o cargo do funcionário não
>   estiver na tabela, ele deverá, então, receber 40% de aumento. Mostre o
>   salário antigo, o novo salário e a diferença.
>   Código    Cargo       Percentual 101  Gerente     10% 102 Engenheiro  20%
>   103   Técnico     30%

*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema no seu codigo encontra-se no bloco abaixo

```
else if (c=101)
{
  ns=s+(s*0.1);
}
else if (c=102)
{
  ns=s+(s*0.2);
}
else if (c=103)
{
  ns=s+(s*0.3);
}
```

A declarações das condições impostas nos if..else não resultam em uma comparação de valores, mas sim em uma atribuição de valores. Sendo assim,no seu caso, independente do valor que for atribuído, caso ele não atenda a condição `if (c<101||c>103)` ele sempre irá atender a condição `if(c=101)` e nunca as demais seguintes pois o valor de c após `if(c=101)` será 101.

Lembre-se, na linguagem C o comando para fazer uma comparação é o `==`

Segue abaixo o seu código com correções

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void){
 float s,c,ns;

 printf ("Cod. do Cargo:");
 scanf ("%f",&c);

 printf ("Salario:");
 scanf ("%f",&s);

 if (c<101||c>103) {
   ns=s+(s*0.4);
 }
 else if (c==101) {
   ns=s+(s*0.1);
 }
 else if (c==102)
 {
   ns=s+(s*0.2);
 }
 else if (c==103){
   ns=s+(s*0.3);
 }

 printf ("Salario Antigo: R$ %.2f",s);
 printf ("\nNovo Salario: R$ %.2f",ns);
 printf ("\nDiferenca: R$ %.2f",ns-s);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perfeito, deixei passar a diferença entre = e ==, muito obrigado!

Comment: @NewtonSandey se a resposta resolveu o problema, podes [aceitá-la como correta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta)!

Answer (score 3):

Pelo que observei em seu código, o erro está na condição. Em C, assim como algumas outras linguagens, o operador relacional para testar a condição de igualdade é "==". Quando você usa apenas um "=" está atribuindo um valor a uma variável, por isso ele está sempre retornando o valor anterior e não a resposta esperada.

Sendo assim, seu `if` ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
if(c == 101){
    //Código a ser executado.
}
```

Comment: Perfeito, deixei passar a diferença entre = e ==, muito obrigado!